# Как передать vector в метод в качестве параметра?

Tags: vector, методы

Почему компилятор может на такой код

```
void Move(char a, vector<int> Area) { /* тело метода */ }
```

выдавать ошибку *syntax error: identifier 'vector'*?

Comment: лучше писать так `std::vector`
и надо передавать либо ссылку либо указатель
`void Move(char a, std::vector<int>& Area)`

Comment: Точно, std! Спасибо, помогло, буду внимательнее)